# Логирование запроса к Postgresql. Golang

Tags: postgresql, golang, gorm

Подскажите, пожалуйста, стоит задача логирования времени запроса к БД, а также функции, откуда был вызван запрос. На данный момент имеется выбор между gorm и pgx. Приложение достаточно большое, поэтому не хотелось бы оборачивать каждый запрос в некую обёртку, а настроить логирование запросов на уровне инициализации драйвера. Спасибо!

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 3):

Кто же поставил такую задачу? Ведь для анализа эффективности работы с базой можно использовать логи самой базы. Если будут обнаружены проблемные запросы, то найти их в приложении обычно довольно просто, то есть функцию логировать не обязательно, вы её легко найдёте по SQL-запросу.

Получается вам надо просто настроить [логирование](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/9.6/runtime-config-logging) в postgresql. Такой подход позволит следить за использованием базы данных без привлечения разработчиков; в коде приложения не появится лишнего кода, который может быть причиной багов; запросы из разных источников не ускользнут от внимания dba.